# Leading and trailing quotation marks are appearing in my output

Tags: .net, f#

I am manually parsing java from an API, outputting to a file, reading the file, adding data and outputting in .tex format.  Everything is working perfectly EXCEPT for a single leading double quote and a trailing double quote in my final output document.tex.

The "HtmlString" should actually be "APIString" ... but this is a work in progress.  Names aren't up to snuff yet.

Here is my code:

```
    let mkStream (data:string) (filepath:string) = 
     use outFile = new StreamWriter(filepath)
     outFile.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" data) 
     outFile.Close()
    let (|->) (data:string) (filepath:string) =
     mkStream data filepath
    let (!<) (filepath:string) = new StreamReader(filepath)  
    HtmlString myRoute_API |-> ftext
    let java    = !< ftext
    let javastr = java.ReadToEnd()
    let jclose  = java.Close()
    let a = parseDirections javastr myStops
    let d = publish javastr a wayptList deliveries |-> fltex
```

I am new to the .NET framework.  However, I cant think of, off the top of my head, why the Writeline function would print the literal string instead of the string inside the quotation marks arising from the sprintf statement.

It seems like a nuance of Windows file output...there is probably a simple answer.

Comment: HtmlString is a .Net class dude. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx

Comment: because I figure there are more C# users than F# users...and this is a problem with WriteLine...and not a problem with F#.  So, C# got a tag as well.

Comment: yes, I found that out when it got syntax highlighting a second ago.  I am new to .NET, like I said.  and...it should be APIstring.  I just gave it that name while I was writing the project.

Comment: If the name is APIstring in your code then post your code.  I wouldn't assume this isn't important to your question if I were you.

Comment: Remove `sprintf "%A"` from `outFile.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" data)`. It might not solve your problem, but it's superfluous.

Comment: It isn't APIstring in my code.  It is HTMLString in my code.  So I copied and pasted it.  It is a misnomer.  It should be APIString, but I didn't name it that, so I made the correction after I posted the code.

Comment: Voting to close because you've asked this question twice, both times without sufficient code to understand or explain your problem. The quotes are apparently not in the code you've shown, so they're either coming from your data or a part of your program you've not posted.

Comment: If you want help, meet us halfway.  Please post the exact code you're testing and please post it formatted properly.  In F# indentation is important.  For example, the APIString under the let (!<)--is it in the body of the function or not?  I can't tell from your formatting.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Solved the problem.  Guess adding the sprintf "%A"  converts the string to it's literal form when combined with WriteLine...and interprets the interior formatting. ... which is why it was a mystifying bug.  I had to implement it to avoid a compiler error when I wrote it originally.   lol.  Weird.

Comment: RE: Onorio Catenacci:: I created a file output "pipe" using the infix notation.  the APIString under the let (!<) is modifying the API query string...and outputting the servers response via the (|->) operator to the file.  All of the relevant code is there.  anyways, once again, thanks Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Re-posting my comment as an answer since it solves the problem.*

Remove `sprintf "%A"` from `outFile.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" data)`.

Comment: that's exactly why there are double quotes, btw, if he used sprintf %s since data is a string, there would not be double quotes, %A adds them

Comment: `sprintf` (with any format specifier) is superfluous inside a call to `WriteLine`.